# What does it mean by $\sup{X_n}\ $

Tags: probability, definition

From [Probability of a supremum of a sequence of independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202469/probability-of-a-supremum-of-a-sequence-of-independent-random-variables)

Person asks the question

"
Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is an independent sequence of random variables. Show that $$P(\sup X_n<\infty)=1$$ if and only if $$\sum_n P(X_n>M)<\infty$$ for some $M.$"

My question is what is the meaning of $\sup X_n\ $.

It seems like it's either

$\sup X_n=\sup\  \{\omega:X_n(\omega)\} $ for all n

or

$\sup X_n=\sup\ \{\omega:X_n(\omega)\ \ \text{for all n}\}.$

It would be great if anyone can clarify this.

Comment: It is neither of your suggestions. For $\omega\in\Omega$ you have a sequence of numbers $\mathbf{x}\equiv \{X_n(\omega)\}$. Then $(\sup_{n\ge 1} X_n)(\omega)=\sup_{n\ge 1}\mathbf{x}_n$.

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sense of the first statement, we have to make sense of the statement:

$$
\sup X_n < \infty
$$
More formally, this is an *event*, as in we must consider the set:
$$
\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega) < \infty\right\}
$$
Thus, we are considering all sample points $\omega$ for which the supremum of the sequence of real numbers, $X_n(\omega)$ (Remember the sample point $\omega$ is fixed) is less than $\infty$.

This in mind, the statement:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_n X_n < \infty\right) = 1
$$
is shorthand for the statement:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega) < \infty\right\} \right) = 1
$$

Comment: Thank you! I completely misinterpreted. Now it makes sense